# Postgres queries on SQL fail to commit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I am using Postgres Hobby version on Heroku.

A particular action on the website checks for the presence of a particular item and it's category in Product and Category tables and if not available, inserts them into the same table.

This process works smoothly on localhost but fails on Heroku. Transactions Rollback immediately after Begin. Here is a sample from Heroku log -

```
2017-06-22T07:44:34.376911+00:00 app[web.1]: [93df2c3b-5573-4b9f-aee9-42983913bbd4]   [1m[36mCategory Load (1.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."category_name" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["category_name", "Sports"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2017-06-22T07:44:34.378385+00:00 app[web.1]: [93df2c3b-5573-4b9f-aee9-42983913bbd4]   [1m[36mProduct Load (0.7ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."asin" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["asin", "B00O0UUK74"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2017-06-22T07:44:34.379228+00:00 app[web.1]: [93df2c3b-5573-4b9f-aee9-42983913bbd4]   [1m[36mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."category_name" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["category_name", "Sports"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2017-06-22T07:44:34.380159+00:00 app[web.1]: [93df2c3b-5573-4b9f-aee9-42983913bbd4]   [1m[35m (0.5ms)[0m  [1m[35mBEGIN[0m
2017-06-22T07:44:34.381849+00:00 app[web.1]: [93df2c3b-5573-4b9f-aee9-42983913bbd4]   [1m[35m (0.5ms)[0m  [1m[31mROLLBACK[0m
```

Comment: Can you run `cat log_file` and post log message? Your posted log message too hard to read.

Comment: sometime it happen to me, I think if your local is working but in remote not working it's probably the contant of the database is different, probably some record in remote is missing, and also check your models for validation rules

Comment: Seems like you have `uniqueness validation` on the model please check

Comment: Have you exceeded the row allowance for an Heroku hobby database plan?